# Is there any application from where my internet speed is being throttled?

Tags: wifi, internet

I have 1mbps connection at home. When I connect my laptop or mobile with wifi I get around 120kBps speed which is ok. But when I connect my MAC book with the same wifi I get no more than 20-30kBps speed.  Same thing happens at office too. There we have 10mbps line but I get same 20-30kBps speed.

Today I am even seeing some strange issues as well. I tried opening wikipedia.org and it showed me only text, css and .js was stripped out. Again I tried opening the page and it opened perfectly. I can't open gmail and facebook at all. But I can access these sites in my laptop right now.

I talked with the admin guy, but he says he did nothing as such.

What could be the issue? How to debug it?

**FYI:**
When I am at home I am not behind any proxy.
I don't have admin rights, so the solution you will give I will pass on to the admin guy. That may help him.

**More**
Just now I pinged www.google.com and it returned:-

> Ping has started…
>
> ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host

But again I can access all sites in laptop.

Comment: Many major web sites are proxied and routers or the OS itself discard ping responses. You might try `traceroute` or `host` rather than using ping to test connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I have high regard for Apple's network diagnostic tool.

Open system preferences and go to Network.

[image: Network preference pane]

Mash the **Assist me..** button and run diagnostics.

It will help you provide detailed status to your network admin or perhaps show you what step along the way is failing.

Comment: Great! I will surely tell this to admin guy. :) Thanks.

Comment: Also, I see in DNS server tab there are 2 DNS servers mentioned. One which is the IP of my wifi. Then there is one more DNS server which I don't what is that. It is fe80::a221:b7ff:febc:d368 .  Can this be an issue?

Comment: If your DNS is messed up, that would surely be a problem. Most people can turn off IPv6 and be just fine, but it's rare to have an IPv6 DNS poison things on a Mac as it's pretty smart about trying IPv4 first for name resolution.

Comment: I tried Assis me > diagnostics . It says "Your Internet connection appears to be workig correctly' I still can't connect to facebook. But using Laptop I can connect right now. Help please.

Comment: I deleted 'fe80::a221:b7ff:febc:d368' from DNS server list, and now somwhow I can access facebook and gmail both. Speed is still throttled to 20kBps.